# Why does the server not receive the ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, proxy, server

I have to test a website with integration tests. The website sends all requests to a proxy:

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    port = (process.env.PORT || 8001),
    server = module.exports = express(),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

// SERVER CONFIGURATION
// ====================
server.configure(function() {
    server.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.url);
        if (req.url.indexOf('/any/thing') === 0) {
            console.log("url: " + req.url + ",\nheaders: " + req.headers + ",\nmethod: " + req.method);
            proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://127.0.0.1:1337'});
        } else {
            //console.log("url: " + req.url + ",\nheaders: " + req.headers + ",\nmethod: " + req.method);
            next();
        }
    });
    server.use('/anything', express["static"](__dirname + "/../public"));

    server.use(express.errorHandler({

        dumpExceptions: true,

        showStack: true

    }));

    server.use(express.bodyParser());

    server.use(server.router);

});

// SERVER
// ======

// Start Node.js Server
http.createServer(server).listen(port);
```

This proxy should communicate with this server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("url: " + req.url + ",\nheaders: " + req.headers + ",\nmethod: " + req.method);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("{'user': 'garrarufa', 'loginToken': 'token'}");
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

To login ajax is used:

```
$.ajax(this.apipath + "/login/", {
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(...){...},
    error: function(...){...}
});
```

When I run the login request, immediately `error`is called. The request does not appear at the proxy server. At least the proxy does not print anything to the console. What is going on here? Shouldn't the ajax request be sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy is running on

```
port = (process.env.PORT || 8001),
```

What port is your client code sending to? I.e. what is this.apipath set to?

```
$.ajax(this.apipath + "/login/", {
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(...){...},
    error: function(...){...}
});
```

Comment: apipath = 'api'. i am not sure what this means because in the original code (which works) it says: `if (hostname === "localhost" || ...) this.apipath = "api";` The proxy also receives many requests. but not this one

Comment: Use Fiddler to see more detailed response from your attempted http request to your proxy.